# How to skip jackson "unwrap-root-value" for certain post request?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am using `spring.jackson.deserialization.unwrap-root-value=true` to unwrap all my request.I tried to use spring actuator to change the log level but am getting "JSON parse error: Root name 'configuredLevel' does not match" exception .

For this jackson is expecting the root name but it is a spring-endpoint.

How can I skip jackson unwrap for this request alone or any other we can do that?

```
URI:http://localhost:8080/test/services/v1/loggers/com.rathna
```

This is my reponse for actuator endpoint.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1548406670397,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Root name 'configuredLevel' does not match expected ('Map') for type [map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'configuredLevel' does not match expected ('Map') for type [map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]]\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8b6500; line: 2, column: 2]",
    "path": "test/services/v1/loggers/com.rathna"
}
```

Need to process all type of request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as request body `{"Map": {"configuredLevel": "INFO"}}` , this would work.